# Facebook Graph API - Same access token for all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have been madly trying to get access token for my users since long. I read at many sites to get it somehow by using getSession() and getting access_token from it... it gives me undefined function error.. I googled that too and all solutions said to use the updated SDK but mine is updated and it still won't work... so I finally got another solution to getting access token but this seems to be giving same access token for all users... any idea where the problem lies? All users certainly can't have same token right?

```
$app_id          = $facebook->getAppId();
            $app_secret      = $facebook->getApiSecret();

            function callFb($url, $params)
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
                ));

                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $result;
            }

            $params=array('client_id'=>$app_id, 'type'=>'client_cred', 'client_secret'=>$app_secret);
            $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
            $access_token = callFb($url, $params);
            $access_token = substr($access_token, strpos($access_token, "=")+1, strlen($access_token));
```

Comment: Yuliy already provided the solution to your problem, but I have a question for you. Are you planning to persist these access tokens? Keep in mind that the access tokens you get from FB do expire, unless you specifically request offline_access when obtaining them. Also, its a potential security risk to store FB users access tokens.

Comment: I have obtained offline_access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are asking for `type=client_cred`, which tells Facebook that you don't want access token for a user, but an access token for the app. This is used for doing things like accessing insights, the realtime updates API, and public data. If you want to get user data, you should not be passing that flag.

If you really do want to roll your own access to the Graph API, you can certainly do that, following the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ .

Comment: Thanks... Can you tell me what should I be using instead of type=client_cred? Or just removing it will do?

Comment: You should not be using anything at all instead of it. The default (which is for standard web server flow) is what you should be using, if you're looking to be making API calls from your web server (as opposed to using Javascript).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Let me try that. 
And yes I am looking to make API calls from web server.

Comment: Eliminating type=client_cred is now giving me 

string(79) "{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Missing redirect_uri parameter."}}"

Comment: Right. Read through the page that I linked you to. The basic idea is that you redirect the user to graph.facebook.com/dialog/oauth, and then after they click through a permission dialog, they get redirected to you with a code, and you then use the code to get an access token.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using the PHP SDK but I don't see any mention of it anywhere in your code.

The proper way is this:

```
<?php

    require('facebook.php');

    $fb = new Facebook(array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => SECRET));

    $user = $fb->getUser();

    // if we have a valid user, we're logged in
    if ($user)
    {
        // do stuff with the API using the $fb object
    }
    else
    {
        // redirect the user to the authentication page
        header("Location: ".$fb->getLoginUrl());
    }
```

Example largely paraphrased from [Facebook's SDK Github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).